# Having a list of shared_pointers to instances of items casted to base class what are cast options to sort items into seprate lists?

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

Say we have a base class `green` and such hieraachy tree:

[image]

We have a list `greenList` filled whith all classes `red`, `blue` etc looking like `green`. We do not create this list we are given it filled with data. We now want to create lists for `red`, `yellow` etc classes. We do have headers for `red` etc classes, we do not want to have `getType` inside `green` class.

How to sort that list `greenList` into lists like `redList`, `yellowList` etc in C++03 (using boost)?

Comment: Are you open to using `shared_dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Als: it is called `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: AFAIR, these casts were commonly know by that, It was only in c++11 that they were deprecated.

Comment: At first glance this seems like a bad code smell to me. Usually in OO, once you have forgotten type information, you should not have to explicetly get it back again. I.e. using a cast should be avoided if possible. There are however multiple techniques though for calling back into methods for which this information was never forgotten. For example each object could expose certain methods (not getType, but similar). Have a look at the iterator pattern by GoF for example. Maybe if you tell us more about the design behind is someone is able to suggest a better way without a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are pointers, use dynamic_cast and check the return value; if they are refs use dynamic cast inside a try/catch block.